# Spatial join 2 polylines without common attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line, spatial-join

I need to spatially join 2 polylines, but the problem is that the tables have nothing in common. Also, one of the tables is 4 times as big as the other one. Essentially, what is need is to combine the 2 layers into one based on location. I tried with buffers, and simple joining didnt work, so I will try spatial joining, but im wondering is there is a surefire way to do the following:

1. A poorly digitized version (has what i need in the take)
2. Properly digitized version ( 4x as big as previou)

If a polyline in  #1 is found to be close to the polyline of #2, and share approximate angles, then it should merge.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Select Layer By Location (Data Management)`, here is the [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000). If you are looking something like this then please elaborate your question.

Comment: What are you hoping to get as a result? It is unclear in your question. If you have two layers, and you are looking for lines from both layers to be selected from within an area, then @Surya is correct, you will want to use select by location. But your question isn't clear as to what you have or what you want to do.

Comment: I think this question will be much clearer if you can **edit** it to include a graphic that illustrates your inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I re-drew the picture, so hopefully you can understand it more now.

Answer (score 1):

So, the after some looking around and playing with it, I have come up with a decent solution

1. Make a buffer around the layer that has the attribute you want. (Each buffer will be different)
   2.Spatial join to the layer that is properly digitized( you want the attribute on)

Tips: In the buffer,i used FLAT, And dissolved over attributes I knew the polylines had in common
The spatial join was a one to one, with match option of : within.

Result: With proper buffers, the attribute from Layer 1 will be in the table of layer2, and you are free to do whatever is needed.